# Need XSLT to generate output from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<Company>

    <EmployeeDetail>
<Employees>
        <name>Vishal</name> 
        <name>Ranvijay</name> 
        <name>Jagmit</name> 
</Employees>
<Employees>
        <name>Verma</name> 
        <name>Sahay</name> 
        <name>Singh</name> 
</Employees>
    </EmployeeDetail> 

</Company>
```

I want to create xslt to create output similar to:

Vishal Verma
Ranvijay Sahay
Jagmit Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*[1]/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">&#160;</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of
      select="concat(., 
                     ' ',
                     ../following-sibling::*/*[position() = $vPos])"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...when applied to your original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpyÂ® -->
<Company>
  <EmployeeDetail>
    <Employees>
      <name>Vishal</name>
      <name>Ranvijay</name>
      <name>Jagmit</name>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
      <name>Verma</name>
      <name>Sahay</name>
      <name>Singh</name>
    </Employees>
  </EmployeeDetail>
</Company>
```

...produces the output you desire:

```
Vishal Verma Ranvijay Sahay Jagmit Singh
```

**Explanation:**

- The first template matches the top-level element. Upon finding it, the XSLT processor is instructed to apply templates to all child elements of the first `<Employees>` element.
- The second template matches any element (which, given that there is only one other call to `<xsl:apply-templates>` in the XSLT, matches any child elements of the first `<Employees>` element). Upon finding such an element, the processor outputs the value of that current element, a space, and the value of the adjoining `<name>` element (meaning, the `<name>` element that exists at the same position as the current element, but within the context of the 2nd `<Employees>` element).

  - Note the use of `<xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">&#160;</xsl:if>` - this outputs a space unless we've reached the last element (thus preventing trailing whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Employees//name">
 <xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:text>
 <xsl:if test="position() != last()" />
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I added a space after each name inside the if statement. The if statement should prevent trailing whitespace.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply still I did not get the right output VishalRanvijayJagmitVermaSahaySingh But I need out
Vishal Verma Ranvijay Sahay Jagmit Singh

Answer (score 0):

Would this be sufficient or does the order matter?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="." /><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply still I did not get the right output VishalRanvijayJagmitVermaSahaySingh But I need out
Vishal Verma Ranvijay Sahay Jagmit Singh